# NLog logger different configuration for different environments

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, nlog

I develop a web application using NLog logger. I want to have different logger configurations for the testing environment and the production environment

Is there a best practice as to how to set the configuration for the NLog logger using existing Xml file?

I want to have a configurable logger both in my test environment and in the production development.

In production environment I make a call in the highest point of the first method fired to

`LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(productionPath);`

In my test environment , I execute this in the assembly initialize methods:

`LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(testingPath);`

Is there a better way to configure my logger dynamically somehow?

Comment: this question does not seem to be related to [tag:unit-testing], IMO tag should be removed

Comment: I think it is, because the main purpose of this question ia to allow different configuration for testing